# Text-Replace in docx and save the changed file with python-docx

Tags: python, ms-word, docx, python-docx

I'm trying to use the [python-docx module](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx) to replace a word in a file and save the new file with the caveat that the new file must have exactly the same formatting as the old file, but with the word replaced. How am I supposed to do this?

The docx module has a savedocx that takes 7 inputs:

- document
- coreprops
- appprops
- contenttypes
- websettings
- wordrelationships
- output

How do I keep everything in my original file the same except for the replaced word?

Comment: What have you tried? You could also get more help giving links to the module.

Comment: https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx

Comment: Almost all those args have good default values. You can pretty much ignore enerything but `outpout` and `document`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it seems to be, Docx for Python is not meant to store a full Docx with images, headers, ... , but only contains the inner content of the document. So there's no simple way to do this.

Howewer, here is how you could do it:

First, have a look at the [docx tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/docx/info):

It explains how the docx file can be unzipped: Here's how a typical file looks like:

```
+--docProps
|  +  app.xml
|  \  core.xml
+  res.log
+--word //this folder contains most of the files that control the content of the document
|  +  document.xml //Is the actual content of the document
|  +  endnotes.xml
|  +  fontTable.xml
|  +  footer1.xml //Containst the elements in the footer of the document
|  +  footnotes.xml
|  +--media //This folder contains all images embedded in the word
|  |  \  image1.jpeg
|  +  settings.xml
|  +  styles.xml
|  +  stylesWithEffects.xml
|  +--theme
|  |  \  theme1.xml
|  +  webSettings.xml
|  \--_rels
|     \  document.xml.rels //this document tells word where the images are situated
+  [Content_Types].xml
\--_rels
   \  .rels
```

Docx only gets one part of the document, in the method **opendocx**

```
def opendocx(file):
    '''Open a docx file, return a document XML tree'''
    mydoc = zipfile.ZipFile(file)
    xmlcontent = mydoc.read('word/document.xml')
    document = etree.fromstring(xmlcontent)
    return document
```

It only gets the document.xml file.

What I recommend you to do is:

1. get the content of the document with **opendocx*
2. Replace the document.xml with the **advReplace** method
3. Open the docx as a zip, and replace the document.xml content's by the new xml content.
4. Close and output the zipped file (renaming it to output.docx)

If you have node.js installed, be informed that I have worked on [DocxGenJS](https://github.com/edi9999/docxgenjs) which is templating engine for docx documents, the library is in active development and will be released soon as a node module.

Comment: Thanks, I did another search for how to do this procedure you outlined and found this other question which shows how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867594/find-and-replace-text-in-docx-file-python

Answer (score 12):

this worked for me:

```
rep = {'a': 'b'}  # lookup dictionary, replace `a` with `b`
def docx_replace(old_file,new_file,rep):
    zin = zipfile.ZipFile (old_file, 'r')
    zout = zipfile.ZipFile (new_file, 'w')
    for item in zin.infolist():
        buffer = zin.read(item.filename)
        if (item.filename == 'word/document.xml'):
            res = buffer.decode("utf-8")
            for r in rep:
                res = res.replace(r,rep[r])
            buffer = res.encode("utf-8")
        zout.writestr(item, buffer)
    zout.close()
    zin.close()
```

Comment: wow, this was brilliant. I've been struggling to find a function like this for a while. Thank you!

Comment: Can you elaborate on this please?

Comment: Yes, what is `rep` supposed to be? Can you post an example of function call to see the passed `rep` value format? Thanks

Comment: `rep` is a lookup dictionary, e.g. ```rep = {'a': 'b'}```

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the docx module from [here](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx)?

If yes, then the docx module already exposes methods like replace, advReplace etc which can help you achieve your task. Refer to the [source code](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx/blob/master/docx.py) for more details of the exposed methods.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the module from there. I used replace to make the changes, but the problem I'm having is that I don't know how to save the changes to the file. This is what I have : 1)document=opendocx('sample.docx')  2)replace(document, "todo", "tada")  3)then what am I supposed to do to save the changes to the doc sample.docx while keeping the same original formatting of the document?

Answer (score 2):

```
from docx import Document
file_path = 'C:/tmp.docx'
document = Document(file_path)

def docx_replace(doc_obj, data: dict):
    """example: data=dict(order_id=123), result: {order_id} -> 123"""
    for paragraph in doc_obj.paragraphs:
        for key, val in data.items():
            key_name = '{{{}}}'.format(key)
            if key_name in paragraph.text:
                paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace(key_name, str(val))
    for table in doc_obj.tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                docx_replace(cell, data)

docx_replace(document, dict(order_id=123, year=2018, payer_fio='payer_fio', payer_fio1='payer_fio1'))
document.save(file_path)
```

Comment: Looks like no need `key_name`. Just `if key in paragraph.text:` is Okay. But the format seems will be missing.

Comment: I agree, I got it working by using `key_name = str(key)` I'm not sure if key could ever not be a string here but yeah

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the methods above is that they lose the existing formatting. Please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55733040/508185) which performs the replace and retains formatting.

There is also `python-docx-template` which allows jinja2 style templating within a docx template. Here's a link to the [documentation](https://docxtpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Thanks, this worked flawlessly for me with a fairly complicated document.

Answer (score 1):

I've forked a repo of python-docx [here](https://github.com/evfredericksen/oodocx), which preserves all of the preexisting data in a docx file, including formatting. Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @ramil, you have to escape some characters before placing them as string values into the XML, so this worked for me:

```
def escape(escapee):
  escapee = escapee.replace("&", "&amp;")
  escapee = escapee.replace("<", "&lt;")
  escapee = escapee.replace(">", "&gt;")
  escapee = escapee.replace("\"", "&quot;")
  escapee = escapee.replace("'", "&apos;")
return escapee
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use python-docx to keep an image on docx.
docx detect image as a paragraph.
But for this paragraph the text is empty.
So you can use like this.
`paragraphs = document.paragraphs for paragraph in paragraphs: if paragraph.text == '': continue`