# How can we Edit Docx file and replace blank fields with actual data and save file with modified content?

Tags: java, python, apache-poi, docx, python-docx

To sum up in short, I have requirement that if a field is blank in docx file, I would replace blank field with actual content and save that document.
Solution can be in Java or Python as well.

I have tried various approaches as well, but doesn't seem to help my cause.
For eg. 
[[Text-Replace in docx and save the changed file with python-docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850227/text-replace-in-docx-and-save-the-changed-file-with-python-docx][1]) 
Using above approach, When I tried to edit document.xml file, but I cant programatically find whether given field is blank or not ?

I have also tried using docx, doc4j in java, and apache poi library as well.
I really cant seem to find any solution for this.

This is sample document. 
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oKzYWP1VCZ1KHkIhksQZ4c_fO349EVZ0/view?usp=sharing][1]

So basically, If Name field is null, Replace it with some value
and If address field / Date field is null, replace it with some value and save document back in its actual format.

Comment: What did you try? How did it fail?

Comment: Hi @zvone, Please refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850227/text-replace-in-docx-and-save-the-changed-file-with-python-docx][1])